# TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property fetch - Sinon, Pact

Tags: mocha.js, pact, sinon-chai

**TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property fetch**

```js
declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface Global {
    fetch: (url: string, options ? : Object) => Promise < any > ;
  }
}
declare let global: NodeJS.Global;

it("should handle fetch throwing an error message", () => {
  const fetchFailure = "Test fetch error!";
  const fetchStub: sinon.SinonStub =
    sinon.stub(global, "fetch").callsFake(
      (url: string, options ? : Object): Promise < any > => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          throw (fetchFailure);
        });
      });
  try {
    return getConfigTest.getData(arguments)
      .then(() => {
        expect.fail(null, null, "Attempt to retrieve when no configuration exists should have thrown exception");
      })
      .catch((reason) => {
        if (reason instanceof someError) {
          expect(reason).to.equals("throwing error");
        } else {
          expect(reason).instanceOf(Error);
          expect(reason.message).to.equals("The request failed.");
        }
      });
  } finally {
    fetchStub.restore();
  }
});
```

**Note: I am calling getData method and getData returning another method handle-fetch and inside handle fetch 'fetch' is getting used which I am stubbing here.**

I am using this method in the Pact integration test. I am stubbing the fetch method and returning my own data without interacting with the actual method.

**Can anybody help me with this. If you need any extra info. Please let me know in the comment section ?**

**Update:-**

```js
export async function getData(arguments): Promise < dataConfig > {
    const json: any = await handle - fetch(`path_to_Api);
  return json as dataConfig;
}


export async function handle-fetch<T>(arguments): Promise<T> {
  let response: any;
  let apiErr: any;

  options = _.merge({
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json"
    }
  }, options);

  try {
    response = await fetch(url, options); // **here is the method which i want to stub**
```

I have written a few tests for the correct id. But I was writing a test in case of failure to fetch the handle-fetch method.

In my other node project, I have done this way and it is working perfectly. But this is a react project. Do I need to install anything specific which I am not getting by default?

Answer (score 1):

1. Assuming you are trying to somehow mock the standard `global`, I don't think you can do it this way. Having attempted to run that code myself, `fetch` is indeed not applied to the `global` object.
2. I'm not sure what relevance this has to a Pact test? Mocking the fetch object would certainly not be something you'd want to be doing as part of a Pact test.

What are you trying to achieve?

Another option would be to create a new collaborating service object that performs the fetch, and mock that out instead.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for answering my question. I wanted to stub the fetch method. I have updated my answer. you can see where the fetch method is written.
I have stubbed the fetch method in a node project in same way but this is a React project. Is there anything to install which I am not getting by default unlike node project.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm sorry. Stubbing global is usually a code smell, so I've avoided it for a while. Typescript can be finnicky!

Comment: Hi, @MatthewFellows, I found the solution by adding a 
node-fetch-polyfill.ts file which is having few lines of code like the declaration of global fetch and an instance from node-fetch package. Btw thanks for your valuable time on this discussion.

Comment: Great, thanks for taking the time to respond to it!